# What is the advantage of using sparklyr with master="local"

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I am totally new to the terms "spark" and "sparklyr" so my questions might not be so good. I understand that one should use spark when the data cannot fit in the memory or RAM. If I connect with master="local" does it mean that I am working locally on my PC? What is the advantage of this. E.g. I have 16 GB of RAM on my computer, will I be able to use more that 16 GB of memory if I use sparklyr?

When connecting to a server: Is it a public server that is made available for eveyone or private server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in `local` mode everything (driver and workers) is **running on your machine**. The advantage is only for testing purpose / usage of Spark features.

## Clusters

Aside from the local mode, you can connect to Spark clusters:

- Standalone cluster: `spark://HOST:PORT`
- Mesos: `mesos://HOST:PORT`
- YARN: `yarn`
- Kubernetes: `k8s://HOST:PORT`

For more detail check this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)

When using a cluster you benefit from the Core and RAM of the cluster to perform computations (done by the workers). However you can decide to run the driver program on the cluster or in your machine. This last point mainly depends on the usage, for an interactive mode (notebook or REPL) you will need to run the driver locally.

## Spark vs Sparklyr

Apache Spark is a Scala framework. Sparklyr is a R interface (package) to Spark permitting to perform Spark computations in a convenient way for R users (using dplyr for example). The main advantage of using Spark is to perform **distributed computing**. This mean being able to breakdown big computings that do not fit in memory in small chunks that can be performed by different process with isolated CPU and memory.

Comment: Thanks! What if I have sensitive data i.e. data that is not allowed for the public to see. Is I safe to connect to the clusters you mention? And does running spark in local mode not provide any benefit at all?

Comment: It depends on the cluster policy you can use multi-tenant clusters that can be shared safely by different users / for different usages. However pay attention to the location of the cluster. Maybe using a cluster running on cloud provider premises does not match your legal constraints.

Comment: I am new to sparklyr. I think that the last part of the question has not been fully answered: "When connecting to a server: Is it a public server that is made available for eveyone or private server...". I mean, connecting to a server implies a paid service?